# I was given a serverless app to work on at work, where to start as a noob?

Tags: mongodb, graphql, serverless

avoiding the obvious answer, "Maybe I shouldn't have been given this to work on."
Let's just assume I was given this as a complex 'test of my abilities to learn on the job'.

The app is using serverless framework and I understand the basics of the structure using AWS and where certain things go etc, but I am not used to the structure of the app i was given.

I have a folder for backend, app, and one for 'graph'. I would just like to know where to start? Is the suggested route to user 'serverless-offline' or being that I didn't design this app, should I go straight to plugging things into my AWS, and get it running that way? I know this is kind of a noob question, and regardless I'm just going to go ahead and start playing around with the two options, but I do have a small window of time to figure out how to get this running in a 'Dev' environment so I can give a quote on adding some new React things to the app.

Answer (score 2):

Are you working for a consulting company that advertised you as an "expert" to a customer where you actually have a severe knowledge gap to even approach the project you've been put on?

If yes, you aren't going to get much more information here in a reasonable sized answer than you can easily find using a web search. In fact, your question is so vague that I personally think it's not answerable at all. So, get searching on your own, hopefully you can figure out enough stuff by the deadline that you/your company can "fake it until you make it".

If not, and you are an employee in a normal company, you should have some sort of knowledge transfer process in place where someone who is familiar with the application would tell you at least an overview of how it works and how to approach it for basic changes. Unless this person left the company and now there is nobody in house with the needed knowledge, which is your boss's/company's problem and - if they are a *good* company - they should give you a reasonable amount of time to figure out all of this stuff the hard way, in which case the answer is - again - get searching the web.

Comment: Yeah i figured as much, and no, it sort of just happened this way because I am part of a small dev team and honestly I don't think the senior wants to touch it. They are good, and my boss does know I have the knowledge gap. Ill stick to tutorials untill something sticks, there is just a lot to mentally unpack with serverless, especially as a junior. Thanks though.